# Why am i getting " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I can't figure out why i am getting this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined "

Here is the code:

HTMl

```
<form method="post" action="" id="security-check">
<input type="text" name ="first" placeholder="First Name">
<input type="text" name ="last" placeholder="Last Name">
<input type="number" name ="dob" placeholder="DOB">
<input type="text" name ="state" placeholder="State">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var fname = input[0];
var lname = input[1];
var dob = input[2];
var rez = input[3];

function idCheck(first, last, date, state){
  this.first    = "Teddy";
  this.last     = "Broosevelt";
  this.date     = 03041894;
  this.state    = "NY";

  if(firstName != this.first){return false;};
  if(lastName != this.last ){return false;};
  if(birthDate != this.date){return false;};
  if(rez != this.state){return false;};
}

input[4].addEventListener('submit', function(e){

  idCheck(fname, lname, dob, rez);
  e.preventDefault();

}, false);
```

Comment: Could you provide your HTML? It looks like you don't have five `input`s on your page.

Comment: `input[4]` is null or undefined.

Comment: Probably because you only have 4 input elements and you're accessing the fifth (0 index arrays)

Comment: actually i just didn't save the fifth element to a variable. the node is still accessible via input[4] because input is a variable.

Comment: The code has multiple mistakes which would prevent it from working, e.g., incorrect use of "this", assigning an octal value to the date, etc.  However, OP is correct that there are 5 inputs with input[4] as the submit button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cannot read property addEventListener of undefined` simply means that your attempt to use the `addEventListener` method of some object can't work because the object that you are trying it on isn't really an object it's "undefined".

So, `input[4]` is the object qualifier you have before `addEventListener`, so `input[4]` is what is `undefined`. You must examine your code to determine why that is. As others have said, you most likely don't have a 5th element being returned to your input nodelist varaible.

**EDIT:**

Now that you've posted more of your code, there are many problems. The biggest of which is that you are wiring up your event handler incorrectly so it will never get called. See my updates to your code and comments below:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   <!-- Don't use hypens in element ids -->
   <form method="post" action="#" id="securityCheck">
     <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="First Name">
     <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Last Name">
     <input type="number" name="dob" placeholder="DOB">
     <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="State">
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
   </form>

   <script>
     // If you wish to work with form events, you need a reference to your form:
     var form = document.getElementById("securityCheck");

     var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
     var fname = input[0];
     var lname = input[1];
     var dob = input[2];
     var rez = input[3];

     function idCheck(first, last, date, state) {
       this.first = "Teddy";
       this.last = "Broosevelt";
       // This should be a date. You had it as a number and that
       // number could be interpreted as an octal because it starts with 0
       this.date = new Date(1894, 2, 4); // Month is zero-based
       this.state = "NY";

       // Where are firstName, lastName and birthDate being declared?
       if (fName != this.first) { return false; };
       if (lName != this.last) { return false; };
       if (dob != this.date) { return false; };
       if (rez != this.state) { return false; };
     }

     // You are attempting to wire up a submit button to the submit
     // event, but a submit button does not have this event, the form does
     form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

       // Calling idCheck may result in a return value of false
       // or it may result in nothing of consequence happening
       // Either way, you are not doing anything with what may
       // or may not come back from idCheck. All this function really 
       // does is ensure that the form never submits
       idCheck(fname, lname, dob, rez);
       e.preventDefault();

     }, false);
   </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Agree - thanks for the correction.  I've removed my comments.

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarcus for the detailed yet concise response.. Noob mistakes : )